# Vector bundles are first cohomology sets

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, vector-bundles

I posted the following question on [math.stackexachange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4521124/vector-bundles-are-first-cohomology-sets?noredirect=1#comment9497486_4521124) and it was suggested that I should repost it here.

Suppose $X$ is a variety, then we have the result that $\operatorname{H}^1(X, \mathcal{O}^*_X)=\operatorname{H}^1_{\acute{e}t}(X,\mathbb{G}_m)=\operatorname{Pic}(X).$ Which also holds in finer sites where coherent sheaves satisfy descent.

I know that a generalisation exists in the non-abelian setting of $\operatorname{GL}_n$, but I do not know exactly how to define $\operatorname{H}^1(-)$. Do you just define it as the set of torsors? Do you define it as a limit of $\check{\operatorname{C}}$ech cohomologies taken over every cover?

My best guess would be to follow the second one, because we want to continue to have something like $0\rightarrow\check{\operatorname{H}}^1(\mathcal{U}, G)\rightarrow \operatorname{H}^1(X, G)\rightarrow \check{\operatorname{H}}^0(\mathcal{U}, \underline{\operatorname{H}}^1(G))$ for a cover $\mathcal{U}$ and a non abelian sheaf $G$ (like in the abelian case using $\check{\operatorname{C}}$ech to sheaf spectral sequence). But this is only a guess, I am not sure.

Most of the answers I have found on the internet suggests I read Giraud's "Cohomologie non abelienne", but my lack of knowledge of French makes that very difficult.

Comment: If you're looking for a readable survey, I would recommend Milne's Lectures on etale cohomology https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/LEC.pdf starting in section 11.